# Symfony console, file paths, /dev/fd/0 trick

Tags: php, symfony, console, heredoc, herestring

I have my own symfony console commands, some of which take a filename as the argument.

eg.
`$ php app/console mycommands:doTheThing /path/to/my/file.txt`

I have tried using the [/dev/fd/0](https://askubuntu.com/q/854921/391426) trick to [use a string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/328234/164283) instead of a file here, however it's still not working.

eg.
`$ php app/console mycommands:doTheThing php://dev/fd/0 <<<'myFileContents'`

Could anybody provide any insight or help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html#PROCESSSUBREF):

```
$ php app/console mycommands:doTheThing <(echo "foobar")
```

Comment: I get `Exception Message: Warning: fopen(/dev/fd/63): failed to open stream: No such file or directory` and then a reference to the line number of the `fopen`.